# JavaScript runs only last function

Tags: javascript

I have the following testing code:
**EDIT:**

```
 var getIt = function () {
      return this.x;  
    };

var obj1 = {
  get : getIt,
  x : 11
};

var obj2 = {
  get : getIt,
  x : 12
};

obj1.get();
obj2.get();
obj1.get();
```

When I run this code, only last function returns value of **11**. So instead of seeing three values, I see only the last one. If I delete last line, I see only **12** Why is that?

Comment: When you run this exact code you should get an error

Comment: This code couldn't work, `getIt` of obj1 is undefined

Comment: Calling obj.get() expects a function, but obj.get is undefined.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that you are running this code in a console or you wouldn't be seeing any value at all. The default behavior of consoles is to display the result of the latest expression.

If you want all values logged, you can explicitly log individual expressions using `console.log`.

```
console.log(obj1.get());
console.log(obj2.get());
obj1.get();
```

Note that your code as is doesn't run, but I assumed it did since you haven't mentioned any errors.

Comment: You are right. I just use online js compiler. And I needed to reload it to see the problem

Comment: @ovod Online interpreters might have a different behavior than consoles, so what I said may not work, but you could use `alert` instead of `console.log`. `"And I needed to reload it to see the problem"`... you mean that it complains about `getIt` being undefined? If that is the case just define it using the function declaration syntax anywhere in your code `function getIt() { return this.x; }`

Comment: @ovod Press F12 in your browser and use that console instead ;)

Comment: The result is the same - it shows only the last return value)

Comment: @ovod Yes, but use the code I provided with `console.log`. It will show all of them.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you've specified `getIt` in `obj2`, so calling first time `obj1` will cause an error.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: getIt is not defined

You should move `getIt` to the top.

```js
var getIt = function () {
  return this.x;  
};

var obj1 = {
  get : getIt,
  x : 11
};

var obj2 = {
  get : getIt,
  x : 12
};

alert(obj1.get());
alert(obj2.get());
alert(obj1.get());
```

Comment: That's not the OP's described behavior. He does state that `obj1.get()` returns `11`. Simply assume that the posted code is incomplete.

Comment: He returns 11 because he runs `obj1.get()` twice: first time before `obj2.get()` and the `getIt` is `undefined`; second time after `obj2.get()` so `getIt` already a `function`.

Comment: As soon as an error is raised the execution stops, so the code wouldn't go further than `obj1.get()`.

Comment: I edited code but it shows only the last line. I suppose it is because of online compiler.

Comment: plalx, actually the initial code didn't "go further than `obj1.get()`". Didn't you try it to run? Also, I guess the author runs the code in some strange way because there is no output for the result.

Comment: @Yuri This is what I just said one comment above ;) Hence, if the OP was getting 11 initially then the posted code was incomplete so the problem had nothing to do with getIt being undeclared. The OP uses an online REPL.